# Standing Bounty

Tags: discussion

I have a few questions that I would like to offer a bounty on that does not expire in 7 days.  Questions that require either a high degree of research and/or a level of experience and knowledge that is not available in the current daily visitors.

I made a  feature request at Meta which is collecting around one vote per 5 views.  [Request new function Standing Bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267021/) (*Currently at -13 with 68 views*) I am guessing it will not be implemented anytime soon.

After thinking about a bit more I am considering making a somewhat standard "template" that I can customize for the particular question and post at the end of a question. It will highlights my willingness to grant a rep bounty using the "Reward Existing Answer" function to transfer rep after an answer has been posted.

The tools available for creating custom formatting are listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) we don't have a sandbox area to play in so I am going to post an answer here where I can workout both the wording and formatting. If anyone else would like to try feel free to post your own 'answer'.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're seeking a research bar that is too high for most Stack sites. Expending a large amount of effort, perhaps many hours, to get a few reputation points isn't really a fair value proposition to be honest. I've actually avoided answering questions where I've seen overly scholarly like demands in the answer, I simply don't have the time for it.

Comment: A good point, two counter points; 1. If we want to have the best answers on the internet we need answers to the hard questions.  2. I have put some long answers into some questions ([1](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/can-rabbits-fart/1508#1508) [2](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7239/what-are-the-navigation-considerations-on-the-monongahela-and-youghiogheny-river/7245#7245) ) it is more than just rep that drives one to research and write these answers.  The added rep is not payment but recognition for a job well done..

Comment: I have to be honest, though, that I don't think people will claim the prize. Scholarly research material is expensive to access, usually, and can require extensive reading and cross-reference checking. For a few points on the Internet? Not sure I see why I would do it.

Comment: Also, I don't think the goal is to create a scholarly answer site, I think the goal is to great a great answer site for the average person. If being too aggressive on research means we get no answers then we're even worse off.

Comment: When I was new to SE I recall the first couple hundred rep points to be the hardest to get.  According to my [pets profile](http://pets.stackexchange.com/users/13/james-jenkins) my questions and answers have reached over half a million people, If one out 100,000 of the next half million take the opportunity to research a difficult question and post a great answer the bounty will give them a good head start and we will have attracted a scholarly contributor.  While I agree that all answers don't need to be overly scholarly, neither do we want be totally without them.

Answer (score 1):

## Standing Bounty

Standing Offer to grant xxx [Reputation Points](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) to a new answer that meets these criteria:

- Criteria One
- Criteria Two

**OR**

- Alternate Criteria One
- Alternate Criteria Two

> There is an existing [bounty system](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) that allows that allows for the transfer of reputation from one user to another with the "Reward Existing Answer" feature, which I will use to transfer some of my reputation to you.

Comment: I have posted this on 3 questions to see what comes of it.  In theory two of the answers should be answerable to anyone who want to do the research.  [Can bonded rabbits die of loneliness?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10380)  & [What does it mean when a rabbit has clear mucus like poop?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10162) & [Other than fire what concerns are there from sweating hay?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9567)

Comment: Note that [one question has been answered](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10380/can-bonded-rabbits-die-of-loneliness) of the three.  It was discovered independent of this post.